# Python3 module to copy string to system clipboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, clipboard

I tried doing some research, but havent seem to come up with something yet, so i figured someone might be able to help.

I want to use my existing python code:

```
decoded_pass = decrypt(
                    param_encoded_salt,
                    param_encoded_password
                ).decode('utf-8')
```

and `copy` its `value` to my system "clipboard".

So if I go into another application and `ctrl+v` it will have the value of `decoded_pass`

How can I do this in `Python3`

Comment: [Google seems to turn up what you're looking for immediately.](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+clipboard)

Comment: @user2357112 - actually text = clipboard.paste() just copies the value to text, not to memory.

Comment: @CodeTalk what "memory" do you mean ? `text = clipboard.paste()` copies from clipboard to text variable and `clipboard.copy(text)` copies from text variables to clipboard.

Comment: @furas - thanks for that explanation! That's really helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [pyperclip](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip). Probably [PyAutoGUI](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) can do it too (the same author).

Answer (score 1):

You could try pyperclip. Website is here: http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/